# Downloading and converting image to base64 results in corrupted data

Tags: node.js, image, download, base64, encode

I try to download an image using [`got`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) and convert it to a base64-encoded string using a Buffer interface as [`responsetype`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#responsetype). My current snippet converts the image and logs the encoded string to the console:

```
'use strict';

const got = require('got');
const imgUrl = 'https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'


got(imgUrl, {
    responseType: 'buffer'
})
.then(response => Buffer.from(response.body, 'binary').toString('base64'))
.then(console.log)
```

I wrote the base64-encoded string to a file by redirecting any terminal output to a file like this:

```
node base64.js >> base64_image
```

I opened the file and copied its contents to an [online base64-image-viewer](http://jaredwinick.github.io/base64-image-viewer/) which shows a corrupted image symbol instead of the desired image.

Is my download and encode approach faulty or did I miss something else? How could I narrow down the issue to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `responseType` property. You have to use [`encoding`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#encoding) property, which defaults to `utf8`

```
got(imgUrl, {
    encoding: null
})
.then(response => response.body.toString('base64'))
.then(console.log)
```

Or directly: `encoding: 'base64'`

```
got(imgUrl, {
        encoding: 'base64'
    })
    .then(response => response.body)
    .then(console.log)
```

Otherwise you're trying to convert back from an `utf8` encoded image, which is why it's broken. You can't convert an image to `utf8` and then convert it back.

Comment: Is `data:image/png;base64` a mandatory part of the encoded string? Do you know how to add this part to the encoded output? I could pre-pend this manually, but I am just wondering how to do this automatically and in turn more flexible/elegant.

Comment: You have to prepend that, if you need it. it's "mandatory" if you want to show that in an `img` tag in the browser. It depends in the use case.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness and for people, stumbling upon my question in the future, let me summarize my final approach which is based on [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55455488/3991125) and pre-pends the required `data:image/png;base64`:

```
'use strict';

const got = require('got');

const imgUrl = 'https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'


got(imgUrl, {
    encoding: 'base64'
})
.then(response => {
    const contentType = response.headers["content-type"];
    const imgData = response.body;
    const encodedImage = `data:${contentType};base64,${imgData}`;
    return encodedImage;
})
.then(console.log)
```